# pythontex returns nothing

Tags: pdftex, pythontex

I want to automatically trim a PDF (cut out e-stamps from a larger sheet and insert them into a letter). That should work like that: I give a number n, to cut out the n-th stamp on the sheet, and for that I wanted to use pyhontex to calculate the coordinates to do so. Here is the working python code for that:

```
n = 9

spalten = 4
zeilen  = 8

xOff = 27.0
yOff = 30.5

xStamp = 32.0
yStamp = 11.5

xSpacing = 38.2
ySpacing = 31.4

left   = xOff + ((n-1) / spalten) * xSpacing
right  = left + xStamp
top    = yOff + ((n-1) % spalten) * ySpacing
bottom = top + yStamp

print("trim={0}mm {1}mm {2}mm {3}mm,".format(left, right, top, bottom))
```

`trim=103.4mm 135.4mm 30.5mm 42.0mm,` would be a sample string which should be used by `\includegraphics` to crop the PDF. So far so good.

The problem is that the file compiles fine but the `pycode` environment does not give anything back. Minimal working sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}
hello\\

\begin{pycode}
print('python test')
\end{pycode}

\end{document}
```

I use `MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.5653 (1.40.16) (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)` via: `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex" ?me" -parse-first-line -shell-escape -enable-write18 -aux-directory="C:\Users\Lenny\Documents\LaTeX\tmp" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try compiling in the three steps `pdflatex`, `pythontex`, `pdflatex`?

Comment: Oh god! Totally missed that part in the manual. Thank you for the hint. Got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile a file using `pythontex` requires three steps.  For example if using `pdflatex` on the main file then you need to at least run

```
pdflatex
pythontex
pdflatex
```

Using a compilation framework such as `latexmk` that is aware of `pythontex` can simplify this process.

Comment: Another thing: Do you have an idea how I can make pythontex use DIR in the --aux-directory=DIR parameter of pdflatex?

Comment: I am not on a windows system so my `pdflatex` does not have that option.  Does `\setpythontexworkingdir{<outputdir>}` do what you want?  Otherwise you should ask a separate question.